# Polymorphic behavior with shared pointers

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I am new to shared_ptr struff. So this may be a silly question, but i have no clue of the error i am getting.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
           base() { cout<<"  base::ctor "<<endl; }
           virtual void print() { cout<<"  base::print "<<endl; }
           virtual ~base() { cout<<"  base::dtor "<<endl; }
};

class derived : public base
{
    public:
           derived() { cout<<"  derived:ctor "<<endl; }
           void print() { cout<<"  derived::print "<<endl; }
           ~derived() { cout<<"  derived::dtor "<<endl; }
};

typedef shared_ptr<base> sPtr;

int main()
{
    vector<sPtr> v;
    v.push_back(make_shared<derived>());
    cout<<endl;
    v.push_back(make_shared<derived>());
    cout<<endl;
//    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](sPtr sp) { sp.print(); });
    for(auto elem : v)
        elem.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
sharedPtr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sharedPtr.cpp:34:14: error: ‘class std::shared_ptr<base>’ has no member named ‘print’
         elem.print();
              ^
```

With my limited understanding, elem should be a shared pointer of type "base", should have called print of derived class as it's a virtual function.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: `elem->print()`

Comment: damn, such an idiot i am, thanx btw.

Comment: Btw, the first choice should be `unique_ptr`, if this is not enough, considering `shared_ptr`

Comment: @Thomas thanx for the the tip, but i am avoiding move for now, hence using shared_ptr not unique_ptr (just experimenting things) :-)